# Boo! A Halloween Code Golf Challenge

Tags: code-golf, string, random

Write a program that takes an input string of length 2 or more characters and adds the string  `~BOO!~`  (that string has a leading and ending space) in a *uniformly random* spot in the string that is not on either end.

---

**Disallowed sample inputs**: `2` or   (an empty input)

**Disallowed sample outputs**: `Hello ~BOO!~`  or  `~BOO!~ Hello` for the input `Hello`

**Sample input**: `Hello, World!`

**Sample outputs**: `Hel ~BOO!~ lo, World!` or `Hello, Worl ~BOO!~ d!`

---

This is code golf, fellas. Standard rules apply. Shortest code in bytes wins.

---

Congratulations to **Dennis** for having the shortest, spookiest program! Happy Halloween!

Comment: Would a command-line argument be okay, or does it have to be stdin?

Comment: Anything that takes an input and prints that output with the modification is acceptable. I use STDIN by default because it's the only term I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
j" ~BOO!~ "cz]OtUz
```

*Thanks to @Jakube for golfing off 1 byte!*

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j"+~BOO%21~+"cz%5DOtUz&input=Hello)

#### How it works

```
                    (implicit) Store the input in z.
                Uz  Compute [0, ... len(z)-1].
               t    Remove the first element.
              O     Select an integer, pseudo-randomly.
             ]      Wrap it in an array.
           cz       Split the input string at that point.
j" ~BOO!~ "         Join the split string, using " ~BOO!~ " as separator.
```

Answer (score 4):

## GML, 91 bytes

```
s=get_string("","")
show_message(string_insert(" ~BOO!~ ",s,irandom(string_length(s)-2)+1);
```

Simple enough - get a string, insert the substring into it, output the string. Done.

Comment: Never thought I'd see GML on codegolf.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 60 bytes

```python
s=input();n=1+hash(s)%(len(s)-1);print(s[:n],'~BOO!~',s[n:])
```

Note:

The modulo of `hash()` will be uniformly distributed over the length of the string. If you think that's bending the rules, note that because of python's hash randomization, this is *actually* random: repeated executions with the same input will give different results.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 20 bytes

```
l_,(mr)/(" ~BOO!~ "@
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l_%2C(mr)%2F(%22%20~BOO!~%20%22%40&input=Hello%2C%20World!)

Explanation:

```
l       Get input.
_,      Calculate length.
(       Decrement, since the number of possible positions is 1 less than length.
mr      Generate random number between 0 and length-2
)       Increment, giving random number between 1 and length-1.
/       Split. Note that this splits repeatedly, but this will not do any harm.
        We will only really use the first split.
(       Peel off the first fragment after the split.
" ~BOO!~ "
        Push the magic string.
@       Rotate the list with the remaining fragments to the top.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pip, 19 bytes

Takes input from the command-line. If the input has spaces or other special characters, it will need to be placed in quotes.

```
a^@1RR#aJ" ~BOO!~ "
```

Explanation:

```
a                    Command-line arg
 ^@                  Split at index...
   1RR#a             ...random integer >= 1 and < length(a) (Python randrange)
        J" ~BOO!~ "  Join on that string and autoprint
```

Comment: Do you mean that the input has to be passed as a single command-line argument, or do you actually have to pass quotes to Pip?

Comment: @Dennis The former. The quotes are to prevent shell expansion, and to prevent stuff with spaces from being treated as multiple command-line args.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 79 bytes

```python
from random import*;s=input();n=randint(1,len(s)-1);print(s[:n],'~BOO!~',s[n:])
```

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/YHYs4R)

Pretty self-explanatory - read a string, pick a random integer between 1 and the length of the string, and print the string with `' ~BOO!~ '` inserted.

Comment: My solution *exactly*. To the *letter*.

Comment: @Mego Seeing a random <code> ~BOO!~ </code> show up in your program is pretty spooky.

Comment: Since multiple arguments to `print` are printed space-separated, you can cut the spaces with `print(s[:n],'~BOO!~',s[n:])`.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 125 bytes

```csharp
using System;class X{static void Main(string[]a){Console.Write(a[0].Insert(new Random().Next(a[0].Length-2)+1," ~BOO!~ "));}}
```

Expanded:

```csharp
using System;
class X
{
    static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        Console.Write(a[0].Insert(new Random().Next(a[0].Length - 2) + 1, " ~BOO!~ "));
    }
}
```

This solution assumes that the string is passed in as the first command-line parameter. This is not usual for C# (stdin is more normal), so I’ve also included a solution that uses normal stdin:

## C#, 139 bytes

```csharp
using System;class X{static void Main(){var x=Console.In.ReadToEnd();Console.Write(x.Insert(new Random().Next(x.Length-2)+1," ~BOO!~ "));}}
```

Expanded:

```csharp
using System;
class X
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var x = Console.In.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Write(x.Insert(new Random().Next(x.Length - 2) + 1, " ~BOO!~ "));
    }
}
```

Comment: (see comments, arguments are ok) `static void Main(string[] x) {Console.Write(x[0].Insert (...) x[0].Length (...)` will shorten your code

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 70 bytes

```julia
print((s=readline())[1:(r=rand(2:length(s)-2))]," ~BOO!~ ",s[r+1:end])
```

Ungolfed:

```julia
# Read a line from STDIN
s = readline()

# Define a random integer within the bounds of s
r = rand(2:length(s)-2)

# Print to STDOUT with boo in there somewhere
print(s[1:r], " ~BOO!~ ", s[r+1:end])
```

Answer (score 1):

### APL, 27 bytes

```
{(-⌽' ~BOO!~ ',⍵⌽⍨⊢)?¯1+⍴⍵}
```

APL doesn't have an insert function, so we rotate the string instead.

```
{                          }    ⍝ Monadic function:
                     ?¯1+⍴⍵     ⍝ Place to insert string, let's say it's X
 (                  )           ⍝ Monadic train:
               ⍵⌽⍨⊢            ⍝ Rotate input by X (⊢) to the left
    ' ~BOO!~ ',                 ⍝ Concatenate ' ~BOO!~ '
  -                             ⍝ -X
   ⌽                            ⍝ Rotate that by X to the right
```

**[Example input on TryAPL](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%28-%u233D%27%20%7EBOO%21%7E%20%27%2C%u2375%u233D%u2368%u22A2%29%3F%AF1+%u2374%u2375%7D%27Walking%20along%20unsuspectingly...%27&run)**

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 75 bytes

```
s=io.read()m=math.random(2,#s/2);return s:sub(1,m).." ~BOO!~ "..s:sub(m,#s)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 35 bytes

34 bytes code + 1 byte command line

```
$-=rand y///c-2;s/..{$-}\K/~BOO!~/
```

Usage:

```
perl -p entry.pl
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, 69 bytes

```
i=input('');a=randi(nnz(i)-1,1);disp([i(1:a) ' ~Boo!~ ' i(a+1:end)]);
```

Inserting a string mid string at a given index in MATLAB is costly in terms of bytes. If there was a simple way to do it, I could save a fair amount by moving to an anonymous function, but I can't find one. Ah well.

Basically it gets a random number between 1 and the length of the string minus 1. Then it displays everything up to and including that index, followed by the `~Boo!~`, and then everything after the index to the end.

---

It also works with **Octave**, so you can try it out online [here](http://octave-online.net/).

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 46 bytes

```ruby
$><<gets.insert(rand(1..$_.size-2),' ~BOO!~ ')
```

Answer (score 0):

## Vitsy, 19 Bytes

Note that `z` and `Z` were edited today, but not for this challenge.

```
I1-R1+\i" ~OOB~ "zZ
I1-                   Get the length of the input, minus 1
   R                  Push a random number from 0 to the top item of the stack.
    1+                Add one to it - this is now a random number from 1 to input
                      length - 1.
      \i              Get that many items of input.
        " ~OOB~ "     Push ' ~BOO~ ' to the stack.
                 z    Get the rest of the input.
                  Z   Output it all.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash/GNU, 61 bytes

```
echo $1|sed "s/.\{`shuf -i1-$((${#1}-1)) -n1`\}/\0 ~BOO!~ /"
```

Takes input string as argument

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 79

```js
r=Math.random()*((x=prompt()).length-1)+1;x.substr(0,r)+" ~BOO!~ "+x.substr(r);
```

It's for the browser console; have fun just popping that in.

Answer (score 0):

## [Chaîne](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Cha-ne/?code%3D%7Bil1-R1%2B%60%7D%20~BOO!~%20%7B%3C%24%2F%7D||input%3D%22Hello%2C%20World!%22), 23 bytes

```
{il1-R1+`} ~BOO!~ {<$/}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>158</s> 154 bytes

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){int i=a[0].length()-2;System.out.println(a[0].substring(0,i=1+(i*=Math.random()))+" ~BOO!~ "+a[0].substring(i));}}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##Xcu7DoIwFADQXylMrTyCroTFyYUwMDgQhitUuFhaAhcSQ@DXK2F0P6eDBQIzSN3VH2tRkxzfUEmWrhMBYcUWgzXrATXPaUTdFCWI9XAMEyiiMlRSN9RyEdzi/DuR7EMzUzgclJTmJ5nm13ReHvmYXD2OlyQFasMRdG16LoTwXLbfs8zZmev9HRQi3jZr7UMqZXz2NKOqnR8)

EDIT: Only now reading program instead of the default function/program in the challenge description.. So added the bordercode with interface and main method.

If a function would be allowed it would be (**<s>99</s> 95 bytes**)

```java
s->{int i=s.length()-2;return s.substring(0,i=1+(i*=Math.random()))+" ~BOO!~ "+s.substring(i);}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##1ZKxbsMgEIb3PMXFE8QxartartR06ZJk6NCh6kBsmpDiw4JzpCp2Xt0lEYq6VM5adEIc9x3/j2AvDzKzjcJ99TWURnoPS6nxOAHQSMp9ylLB6pwCvJLTuIWSxYXnedjvJ2HyJEmXsAKEAgafPR5DN@jCC6NwSzvGs4fcKWodghe@3fjLEexurov7lOlZsZS0E05iZWvGOU8TOC3W6@kJkvR3g@Z5P5xlQzTtxgTRqH2wuoI6eI/23j9A8mj825OqhW1JNKFEBhmKkiUvyhg7hzfrTDVN@OU6f9NPi@dRZnYdo2godTdojiJd96@Q67Py@Hv64Qc)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                        // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  int i=s.length()-2;       //  The length of the input - 2
  return s.substring(0,i=1  //  Return the first part of the input from index 0 to 1
    +(i*=Math.random()))    //    + a random integer between 0 and length-2
   +" ~BOO!~ "              //   appended with the literal " ~BOO!~ "
   +s.substring(i);         //   appended with the rest of the input-String
}                           // End of method
```

Answer (score -1):

## TeaScript, 30 bytes

```
xh(j=N(xn-1)+1)+' ~BOO!~ '+xS(j)
```

Very straight forward.

Answer (score -1):

### CJam, 19 bytes

```
q_,mr)/(" ~BOO!~ "@
```

Comment: This will fail when `mr` returns `0` or `1`, because neither `-1` nor `0` are valid for splitting a string with `/`.

Comment: Then it must be )

Comment: Now it can put `BOO` at the end of the string, You'd also need a `(` before `mr`. But then it's identical to this answer: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62355/8478

Comment: I use q (reads all input, including newline), he uses l (reads only 1 line)

Comment: Oh okay, then you should specify that your code expects the input to have a trailing linefeed (because it doesn't necessarily have one, in which case `q` and `l` are synonymous).

Comment: Wait, actually that doesn't solve the problem. I means that `BOO` could be placed *after* the linefeed which is yet another character too far away.

Comment: In some implementations, linefeeds can be put as part of one input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32927/discussion-between-martin-buttner-and-username-ak).